# How to get in jQuery `title` and `url` value from every object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[{
    "pk": 1,
        "model": "core.website",
        "fields": {
        "title": "Contact",
            "url": "http://www.blog.optivitanutrition.pl/2013/11/najzdrowszy-owoc-swiata/",
            "vimeo": "",
            "youtube": "",
            "content": "",
            "add_date": "2013-11-28T17:17:12.273Z",
            "user": 1,
            "date": "",
            "order": null
    }
}, {
    "pk": 2,
        "model": "core.website",
        "fields": {
        "title": "sadasasdasd",
            "url": "http: //www.blog.optivitanutrition.pl/2013/11/najzdrowszy-owoc-swiata/",
            "vimeo": null,
            "youtube": null,
            "content": null,
            "add_date": "2013-11-30T22:34:12.175Z",
            "user": 1,
            "date": null,
            "order": null
    }
}, {
    "pk": 4,
        "model": "core.website",
        "fields": {
        "title": "agasdgasdgasd",
            "url": "http: //google.com",
            "vimeo": null,
            "youtube": null,
            "content": null,
            "add_date": "2013-12-01T07:36:21.076Z",
            "user": 1,
            "date": null,
            "order": null
    }
}]
```

How to get in jQuery `title` and `url` value from every object? This is my response from backend script.

Comment: Your data is an array, you have to iterate through it. like `data[0].fields.title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"This is my response from backend script."*

OK, so assuming that object ends up in a variable called `response` you can just use a simple loop to access each object in the array in turn:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    console.log(response[i].fields.title);
    console.log(response[i].fields.url);
}
```

(Where obviously you'd do something more exciting than just output the values to the console.)

But if that's not enough jQuery for you, use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.fields.title);
    console.log(item.fields.url);
});
```